# Deriving $\sum_{k=1}^\infty 1/k^2$ when $k$ is odd

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Specifically using that
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(n - \alpha)^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\alpha\pi)},$$ how can I derive 
$$\sum_{k \;\text{odd}, \;k \ge 1} \frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{8}?$$

I've been fiddling with this for ages and I can't think of an appropriate value of $\alpha$ to choose. I feel like I'm missing the obvious!

Any pointers?

Comment: Do you have to do it that way?  It's easier to compute the even series and subtract.

Comment: @lulu Yes, I do. I've seen and understood what you're referring to, but the goal is to derive the second identity from the first.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem#Euler.27s_approach

Comment: There are not so many reasonable values of $\alpha$ to plug in the first equation in order to derive the second one. Did you try any of them?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I found what I was missing, I did make a big oversight in my initial thinking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: If $k$ is odd, it can be written as $k = 2n - 1 = 2 (n - \frac{1}{2})$. This suggests a potential value for $\alpha$.

Answer (score 3):

Put $\alpha=1/2$, and one sees that $\dfrac{1}{(n-1/2)^{2}}=\dfrac{4}{(2n-1)^{2}}$.